# Print array in random order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random

I'm trying to output a javascript array of 4 items in a random order. Problem is, I can only get one to print randomly, like this:

> Sequence:
>
> Diet Coke

..but I would like it to print something similar to:

> Sequence:
>
> Diet Coke
>
> Psuedo Coke
>
> None-psuedo Coke
>
> Coke Zero

..in a random order, of course.

```
<div id="test1"></div>
<div id="test1-drinks"></div>

<script>

    var contents=new Array()
    contents[0]='Coke Zero'
    contents[1]='Diet Coke'
    contents[2]='Psuedo Coke'
    contents[3]='None-psuedo Coke'


    var i=0
    var random
    var spacing="<br>"
    while (i<contents.length){
        random=Math.floor(Math.random()*contents.length)
        document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = "Sequence:<br>";
        if (contents[random]!="selected"){
            document.getElementById('test1-drinks').innerHTML = contents[random]+spacing;
            //mark element as selected
            contents[random]="selected"
            i++
        }
    }

</script>
```

I was hoping the while-loop would cover that for me, but it's not.. Any help is appreciated, and languages php, jQuery and JavaScript are all much welcome.

EDIT: Script's from [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/randomorder.shtml), but I don't want document.write to be used to I tried fixing it up.

Comment: [The procedure to follow is called "shuffling".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

Comment: @Pointy I'll give that a Google. Thing is that this script was working, till I tried to adjust it, and I can't see why it isn't working as of right now.

Comment: Why you tag `PHP`?

Comment: @AlgernopK. no need to google - my comment is a link to the Wikipedia page.

Comment: I don't have any flag remaining. Could someone flag the question as the 1000th duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. Adjusted:

```
document.getElementById('test1-drinks').innerHTML = contents[random]+spacing;
```

to

```
document.getElementById('test1-drinks').innerHTML += contents[random]+spacing;
```

so I wouldn't keep replacing the randomized order.

Answer (score 2):

You could splice the array with a random index until the array is empty.

```js
var contents = ['Coke Zero', 'Diet Coke', 'Psuedo Coke', 'None-psuedo Coke'];

while (contents.length) {
    document.write(contents.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * contents.length), 1) + '<br>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:
Define your array:

```
var contents=new Array()
    contents[0]='Coke Zero'
    contents[1]='Diet Coke'
    contents[2]='Psuedo Coke'
    contents[3]='None-psuedo Coke'
```

Step 2: Randomly order the array:

```
contents.sort(function() {
  return .5 - Math.random();
});
```

Step 3: Print the values:

```
$.each(contents, function(index,value) {
    document.getElementById('test1-drinks').append(value + "<br/>");
});
```

**Your problem**

1. You add 1 to `i` even after you collide with a value that was already selected, so you will not always print 4 times.
2. You override the data each time you print using `innerHTML =`. You need to allow for the old html to stay there, by using append.

Comment: i would not use sort for a single loop task.

Comment: Clearly the creation of the random ordering can be implemented in a better way performance wise. However, it is not relevant to the question. OP can decide for him/herself what implementation he/she wants to use to create the random ordering, though I like this method for examples like these because of its compactness.

Comment: Also, unless you were not talking about the time complexity of this solution, sorting once is less costly then splicing `n` times, as a single splice is `O(n)` complex, resulting in a `O(n^2)` complex solution as opposed to the `O(n log n)` complex sorting method. No offense taken!